# keep getting ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED exception when calling TravelItineraryReadRQ

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller, sabre

i am facing ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED exception in my code

my Request to Sabre

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TravelItineraryReadRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="3.9.0">
  <MessagingDetails xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/res/tir/v3_10">
    <SubjectAreas>
      <SubjectArea>DEFAULT</SubjectArea>
    </SubjectAreas>
  </MessagingDetails>
  <UniqueID ID="XXXXXX this is changed" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/res/tir/v3_10" />
  <ReturnOptions xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/res/tir/v3_10" />
</TravelItineraryReadRQ>
```

Kindly Help me in this exception

Answer (score 1):

The one below works for me:

```
<TravelItineraryReadRQ Version="3.9.0" TimeStamp="2012-09-19T10:00:00-06:00"
xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
 <MessagingDetails>
 <SubjectAreas>
 <SubjectArea>FULL</SubjectArea>
 </SubjectAreas>
 </MessagingDetails>
 <UniqueID ID="XXXXXX"/>
<ReturnOptions UnmaskCreditCard="false"/>
</TravelItineraryReadRQ>
```

Did you also set the headers correctly?